# Using $this outside of the class

Tags: php, oop

I have a class which I'm extending for almost every database table for my records. So far everything was ok, but I need using `$this` on a called function.

This is my class for example:

```
class myClass
{
    public function __call($method, $args)
    {
        if (isset($this->$method)) {
            $func = $this->$method;
            return call_user_func_array($func, $args);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my function to test:

```
$testFunction = function($variable1) {
    $this->_temp_instance = clone $this;
}
```

And I'm assigning to my class:

```
$class_instance = new myClass();
$class_instance->new_assigned_function = $testFunction;
$class_instance->new_assigned_function();
```

I'm getting error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in...
```

Can I make it without editing the extendable class or inherited classes?

I have *toooooo* many classes :/

Thank you.

Comment: what's the purpose of `this` in the test function? you can use traits if you want to share  methods across classes, check them out.

Comment: @Ali, that's for just showing my main reason so far... My purpose is reaching class' properties, methods etc.

Comment: If you want metadata about objects and classes, why not use the built-in Reflection tools?  https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

Comment: To me it seems like you lack common understanding of OOP and just trying to reinvent the wheel, which would carry 4 carriages, whilst common sense dictates the opposite - you need 4 wheels to carry 1 carriage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve *(and why you want to achieve this)* seems **very hacky** to me and what you're after is almost certainly solvable some other, cleanier way, but - to answer your question...

**You can [bind the closure](http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php)**.

```
$instance = new myClass;
$boundFunction = $testFunction->bindTo($instance, $instance);
$instance->func = $boundFunction;
$instance->func();
```